# Running a .NET Framework Web App inside of a docker container generates a 403 response

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile, .net-4.8

I am trying to build a container for a rest api roughly following this https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/tree/main/samples/aspnetapp example here. This all looks very straightforward based on their example. However when I run it I get a `**403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.**` response from the very simple heart beat controller. With no authorization defined anywhere. IIS version is 10.

```
public class HeartBeatController : ApiController
{
  // GET: api/HearBeat/5
  public HttpResponseMessage Get()
  {
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
  }
}
```

I have looked at changing the `ACL` for the directory and it sits nicely inside the IIS directory. But there are no steps in that [example Dockerfile](https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/blob/main/samples/aspnetapp/Dockerfile) that do anything other than copy the build output from the first step into the second.

```
PS C:\inetpub\wwwroot> ls


    Directory: C:\inetpub\wwwroot


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       11/15/2022  10:16 AM                Service2
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 AS build
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
COPY /Service1/*.csproj ./Service1/
COPY /Service1/*.config ./Service1/
COPY /Service2/*.csproj ./Service2/
COPY /Service2/*.config ./Service2/

RUN nuget restore

COPY /Service1/. ./Service1/
COPY /Service2/. ./Service2/

# copy everything else and build app
RUN msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:ProcessorArchitecture=x86 -r:False

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8 AS runtime
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=build /app/Service2/bin/. ./Service2/
```

Comment: I don't think steps like `COPY --from=build /app/Service2/bin/. ./Service2/` ever works. The runtime image you chose has its default IIS configuration (a single site points to a fixed location), so if you don't override IIS configuration to set up your own sites/applications, merely moving the binaries into the container won't set up anything.

Comment: You might try to use IIS Manager to remotely configure the container to the right state first, https://halfblood.pro/remote-management-of-containerized-iis-instances-on-windows-server-core-f6864c74917f. Then you know what changes are needed in `Dockerfile` and add a few more commands (PowerShell script to manipulate IIS configuration).

Comment: @LexLi Has right. If you read carefully on Dockerfile of the provided GitHub repo, you can notice that it copy all bin to `/inetpub/wwwroot` dir which is the default host.